# How to export to file with bcp with header

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

Hi i have query working file to export to .txt file , i just want to add header , any help would be much appriciated , the column name is much appriciated

declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select top 50 * from [Alltrigger].[dbo].[customlook]" queryout \live-ftp\sftp_upload\allfile\saad_test.txt  -c  -t^| -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql 
--- header file 
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "select
      'provided column name' " queryout \prod-ftp\sftp_upload\allstate\header.csv  -c  T -t'

Please reply , i have tried to make header file seprate but its not working

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use queryout option for bcp, and build your column list via string literals. You can get rid of the dynamically generated SQL too.

```
bcp "select '[guid]', 'uploadDate', 'fileName', 'email', 'profileTypeID', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'prospectID', 'prospe‌​ctingPermission', 'relationshipPermission', 'advicePermission', 'transactionalPermission', 'p‌​olicy', 'postalCode', 'language', 'phone', 'businessPhone', 'cell', 'country', 'province', 'city', 'expiryDate', 't‌​ransactionDate', 'source', 'consentBy', 'agentNumber', 'aia', 'suppression' union all select * from [Alltrigger].[dbo].[custom]" queryout \\prod-ftp\sftp_upload\allstate\mark_test.txt -c -t^| -T -t
```

Comment: hi  greg , i have tried it , its not working , so its like select 'col','col2' now at the end do i have  to do from any_table or not ...please advice

Comment: Please see my repro above.  there is as UNION ALL.  If you are still confused, please share your complete statement that you just tried.

Comment: Hi greg , thanks for your responce , i did it but giving me error on first column , should  i send you my code here

Comment: yes, post your repro, that is the only way to see what is wrong.

Comment: declare atsql varchar(8000)
select atsql = 'bCP "select '[guid]', 'uploadDate','fileName',email,profileTypeID,firstName,lastName,prospectID,prospectingPermission,relationshipPermission,advicePermission,transactionalPermission,policy,
 postalCode,language,phone,businessPhone,cell,country,province,city,expiryDate,transactionDate,source,consentBy,agentNumber,aia,suppression union all select * from [Alltrigger].[dbo].[custom]" queryout \\prod-ftp\sftp_upload\allstate\mark_test.txt  -c -t^| -T -t' + atatservername  
exec master..xp_cmdshell atsql  (at = @)

Comment: all your column names need to be string literals, thus you need to put them in quotes.  I will update my repro above.

Comment: still not working tried it before , error : incorrect syntax near 'guid' , copied you , same error @Greg

Comment: Can you try validating the entire TSQL statement in SSMS first?

Comment: Hi greg i fixed it , but its not running inside stored procedure but running as stand alone statement , any idea

Comment: hi greg , is concat "variable" in filename is compatiable in bcp , please advise @Greg